# WIX installation fails when installing COM dll to GAC

Tags: ms-access, com, wix

I am creating an installer which will use a .NET COM component for our Access application. When I installed the COM dll to INSTALLDIR, it is working fine. I leave it to WIX to do the COM registration by running heat to harvest both the dll and the tlb. But now we want to install the dll to GAC, and only the tlb file will be installed in the INSTALLDIR. Our target is that different versions of our SW (it is OK to install them on the same machine) can use the same COM version and after uninstalling one version of our SW, the others will still work(this can't be achieved when we install the dll into INSTALLDIR, am I right?. If my way is wrong, please correct me).

Here comes the problem: in order to install it into GAC, I guess I am supposed to add a  Assembly=".net" to the dll file declaration. However, during the installation, I get this error:
"A problem was encountered in error handler: Automation error The system cannot find the file specified." when I am calling one COM method (Access reference that we created) in the commit phase, i.e., after the COM is registered. Apparently my COM was not registered successfully. But I don't really know why this happens. As I mentioned, the only change I made was to add this Assembly=".net". Before that, the COM registration is OK and I was calling it successfully.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work as the GAC is for .net based dll's and will not accept COM dll's. To see for yourself try and drop the dll into the folder C:\Windows\assembly, you will get an error saying it doesn't have an assembly manifest.

What you should do is keep the Component GUID the same for all versions of your installer for that particular COM dll. This way windows installer will keep note of which applications are using it and only un-install it once the last one is removed. I would also put that into it's own installation folder otherwise you will get an application installation folder left over when the first installed version is un-installed.

Another option is to separate it into it's own installer and use a bootstrapper to install them together.

Comment: Thanks again. Regarding the COM registration, in order for Windows installer track down the COM components, what Guid I should maintain the same and what I should let WIX to assign? As you mentioned, the Component Guid of the COM dll should always be the same. But there are some others: The one for the ClassInterface of my COM interface class(I assume I should keep them the same for different versions). And the one for the tlb Interfaces, which have the same interface name as dll interfaces with a preceding underscore(_). Should I keep them the same as well?

Comment: Yes anything related to the COM+ lib should stay the same. When you use heat to harvest the dll you can use the "-gg" switch and that will generate all the required GUID's for you.

Comment: Yes I know the -gg switch, and it is actually why I am asking: it  generates a new GUID every time heat is ran, which I guess is the opposite to "keeping GUIDs the same". Currently I am running heat every time my installer project is built. I remembered somebody said heat should be ran only once, or at least more statically, but they did create the MSBuild task HeatFile, which I am using, so heat will run every time the installer is built. Is it desired to generate a new GUID in this case?

Comment: And I am using a xsl to modify the GUID to keep the DLL component's GUID always the same. So I can do that to other GUIDs as well, but it just doesn't sound like the right way in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah for the COM dll's I only ever run heat once and then save the wxs file in my project. In my case it will very rarely change and isn't worth setting up to run every build. The only things I use heat for on every build is things that change regularly, for example we package a third-party's database creation scripts and as these are released once a month I use heat to generate on each build.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the experience. I'll see what suits us the best. We don't separate the development and build for different developers, so I have to make the installer as simple as possible and everybody can build it.

Comment: No probs. In that case I would suggest coding everything in wxs files, heat is a bit confusing if you don't know what is going on, at least with static files people can see them! :)